# How to prove $n^n \gt 1\cdot3\cdot.....(2n-1) $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I am stuck with the following problem :

> prove that : For $$n \ge 2, n^n \gt 1\cdot3\cdot.....\cdot (2n-1) $$

Can someone explain it as even though I tried it it was not fruitful and all my efforts went in vain..
Thanks in advance for your time.

Thanks a lot for the numerous responds..After posting the problem, I just realised that it can be done by using A.M. > G.M. as done by 
Michael Rozenberg.

Comment: Hint: The sterling formula is asymptotically identical to the factorial. Write both of your functions as $lim_{n->\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$ and interpret the resulting limit. If you need help evaluating this limit use L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: Combine the lowest factor with the largest factor and compare that to $n^2$ ?

Comment: It is not true...

Comment: @TheodorJohnson Does it prove the inequality for all $n$?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Problem: There are $n$ factors on one side and $2n-1$ factors on the other. You'll run out on the left side and still have a lot of terms remaining on the right. In fact, you could compare it to $n$ instead of $n^2$ and show that the inequality necessarily goes the other way around.

Comment: Ah, yes. I miscounted.

Comment: @Hanul Jeon If it is true I do not see why not.

Comment: Maybe $n^n \lt 1\cdot 2\cdot3\cdot.....(2n-1)$? Otherwise it's false.

Comment: Try this: $2^2 = 4$ compared to $1\cdot 2\cdot 3 = 6$. Now go for $3^3 = 27$ compared to $1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4 \cdot 5 = 120$.

Comment: The claim is that $n^n>(2n-1)!$. It isn't true even for $n=1$ or $n=2$.

Comment: Depending on what the real question is, the observation that for $n\ge a$ $n^2\ge a(2n-a)$ because $(n-a)^2=n^2-2an+a^2\ge 0$ may be useful. There is just one simple equality case and the factors at the beginning and end of the product can be paired off. But this is only useful if there are the same number of factors on each side.

Comment: Same question here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1870309/42969 and here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/120442/42969 and here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1897775/42969.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean the following.

> For all natural $n\geq2$ prove that:
>   $$n^n>1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot...\cdot(2n-1).$$

If so, we can prove it by AM-GM:

$$n^2=1+3+5+...+2n-1>n\sqrt[n]{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot...\cdot(2n-1)}$$ and we are done!

Comment: but this is not the question!!!

Comment: @MANMAID The questioner made a small typing mistake.

Comment: @MANMAID I agree with you! See better my post, please.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Thanks a lot for rectifying the mistake.

Comment: @learner You are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

The original inequality is false: take $n=2$ then $2^2 = 4 < 6 = 3!$.

However, the reversed inequality $n^n < (2n-1)!$ holds for $n\ge 2$. It can be proven by induction: if it holds for $n$, then
$$(n+1)^{n+1} = (n+1)^n (n+1) = n^n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \cdot (n+1) < (2n-1)! \cdot \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \cdot (n+1)$$

so the only thing we prove is
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \cdot (n+1)< 2n\cdot (2n+1).$$
The last inequality follows from $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \le e < 4$ and $4n+4\le 2n(2n+1)$ for $n\ge 2$.

Comment: The reverse inequality is kinda obvious since there are $n$ terms $\geqslant n$ on the right side and all but one are strictly greater than $n$.

Answer (score 1):

There are already two proofs, but I think this one is more intuitive :
$$
1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdots (n-1)\cdot  \underbrace{n \cdot (n + 1) \cdot (n+2) \cdots (2n-1)}_{n\ \text{terms that are all } \geq n} \geq [1\cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdots (n-1)]\cdot n^n \overset{(*)}{>} n^n
$$
$(*)$ Assuming $n > 2$

Answer (score 0):

Using the fact that $n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi n}(\frac{n}{e})^n$, we know that
$$\infty=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{4\pi n}(\frac{2n}{e})^{2n}}{2n^{n+1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{2n*n^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2n-1)!}{n^n}.$$

Thus, your claim is false and in fact $n^n<1*2*3*...*(2n-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

> $n^n < 1\cdot 2\cdot3\cdot…(2n-1)$

Now $$1\cdot 2\dots \cdot(2n-1)=(1\cdot \overline{2n-1})\cdot(2\cdot \overline{2n-2})\cdots(k\cdot \overline{2n-k})\cdots n$$

Now  for $1\leq k\leq 2n-1$ if, for some $k$, $k\cdot \overline{2n-k}\leq n$ then we will have $$2nk-k^2\leq n\Rightarrow k^2-2nk+n\geq 0\Rightarrow 4n^2-4n<0\Rightarrow n\leq 0$$

Thus $k\cdot \overline{2n-k}>n$

This follows the statement is true.

---

---

I guess as @Michael Rozenberg said, this was not actually the question. But since his answer is elegant I am not giving the answer of the question what OP intended to say.(Although he/she did not edited until now, so...)